# Need data on # of syllables per word in languages with CV & CVC syllables only

Tags: phonology, lexicon

In languages with limited syllable structures (CV and CVC), how can I get data on the respective percentages of words in the known vocabulary that have 1 syllable, 2 syllables, 3 syllables, and 4 syllables?    e.g.

In nonce language X, 20% of the words have one syllable, 40% have two syllables, 30% have three syllables, and 10% have four syllables?

Approximations will suffice.

Comment: "known vocabulary" is probably a bad normaliser, because lesser used words tend to be longer than the most frequent words—the effect will be a dependency on the size of the known vocabulary! It is better to normalise either on a corpus that is typical or use word frequency lists and ask for TOP-X (1000, 10000).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply count the vowels per word, as with those syllable structures the number of vowels is equal to the number of syllables: each CV or CVC pattern has exactly one vowel.

This is only problematic if you process written text and some letters can be both vowels or consonants, such as /y/ in English. But that might be resolvable through context, eg if /y/ is followed by a vowel, it would itself be a consonant, as in *yell*, *yawn*, etc.

Comment: There are other potential issues: Spelling conventions like double vowel letters for long vowels, things like the French spelling "ou" for /u(:)/, diphthongs, but I agree that in principle a relatively simple syllable counter can be written in a few dozen lines of code.

Comment: @jknappen Yes -- it's a simplification, and will not give 100% accurate results. If there are specific conventions in the language you're looking at, you can code for it. The /ou/ case could be covered by the CVC pattern: you cannot have two adjacent vowels. The other question is: how important is it to have the odd mistake? Always a trade-off between effort you put in and accuracy.